# Type mismatch when extracting Int with cmdArgs

Tags: haskell

I try to use CmdArgs to extract an integer from the command line arguments:
./prg --byte=512

The below code does not compile and the compiler says `` Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Strlen -> Int' ``. Now, I thought that I had deemed byte to be an integer? Isn't it?

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import System.Console.CmdArgs

data Strlen = Strlen {byte :: Int} deriving (Data, Typeable)

strlen = cmdArgsMode $ Strlen {byte = def} 

main = do
        n <- cmdArgsRun strlen 
        let datastring = take byte $ randomRs ('a','Z') (mkStdGen 3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select the `byte` field from `n` you need to say `byte n`.  So

```
let datastring = take (byte n) $ randomRs ('a','Z') (mkStdGen 3)
```

Comment: It works but it doesn't the funny thing is that my part works, but later in main I use criterion. Criterion bench then picks up the command line args and gets confused. Can I empty the cmdargs somehow so that criterion doesn't see them?

Comment: @JFritsch: I believe you can; ask a new question and make it clear exactly what isn't working/what you need, and you'll get answers.